# Scaling Images Proportionally in CSS with Max-width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Right now, I'm using max-width to scale images to fit. However, they don't scale proportionally. Is there a way to cause this to happen? I'm open to Javascript/jQuery.

If possible, is there a way to do this without knowing the original dimensions of the image (maybe determine this using Javascript/jQuery)?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You need to specify the original width and height:

```
<img src="/whatever" width="100" height="200" alt="Whatever" />
```

And then use something like this in the CSS:

```css
#content img { max-width: 100%; height: auto }
```

You could try this with jQuery if you don't have the width and height up front, but your mileage may vary:

```
$(function(){
    $('#content img').load(function(){
       var $img = $(this);
       $img.attr('width', $img.width()).attr('height', $img.height());
    });
});
```

Obviously replace `#content` with whatever selector you want to scope the functionality to.

Comment: This helped: "You need to specify the original width and height..."

Comment: You dont need the original dimensions (though it is a good practise to add them to the img tag).. http://jsfiddle.net/PYxYv/

Comment: I thought adding `width` and `height` HTML attributes was deprecated in favor of CSS.

Comment: I'd like to point out... I'm sure this works but Chris Redford's answer below was simple and effective.

Comment: With this solution then a slow-loading image will change the page layout when it finally loads. Depending on the image and where it is on the page, this can be horrible for usability.  I'm sure we've all used sites where the page "jumps" just as you're about to click on a link because a banner ad loaded that didn't have an initial height set - it's incredibly annoying.  If anyone has a solution that allows you to set an initial height *and* have the image retain aspect-ratio when resized by a max-width, then I'd be glad to hear it.

Comment: I *love* this answer. I wish it hadn't taken me 10 years to come across this technique though. <groan>

Answer (score 137):

Contrary to the accepted answer, you can do this without specifying the size in the HTML. It can all be done in CSS:

```
#content img { 
    max-width: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Please upvote this answer instead of the accepted one. This is more correct, cause you actually DON'T need to set width/height of the image in HTML. Pure CSS works just fine.

Comment: Appears a solution (from having key ‘height: auto;’ ) ...well at least SOME TIMES AS/BUT **What's the reason the ‘width: ..'?** --indeed as I guessed I found that not needed (in my 1 test, in both Chrome & Firefox) plus 2 other reasonably-voted up answers here, #answer-2077065 & #answer-23001224 , don't do that & 2nd solution even says ‘Don't set your width..’ telling that's problems; but STILL this answer doesn't tell why it does that, so I just down-voted this answer esp as it's gotten so many up-votes (now still 62) its seemingly (big) mis-ranked over those other 2 answers with max 9 votes.

Answer (score 13):

when setting up constant width use:

```
height: auto
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's how to do it with no Javascript. Set your `max-width` to the length you want.

```
#content img { 
   max-width: 620px;
   height: auto;
}
```

This worked for me tested on a Mac with Firefox 28, Chrome 34 and Safari 7 when I had no width or height settings explicitly set in the `img` tags.

Don't set your width in CSS to 100% after the `max-width` setting as one person suggested because then any images that are narrower than the width of the container (like icons) will be blown up much larger than desired.

Answer (score 1):

hopefully it is not too late , but with this pease of code i managed to get proportional images in my gallery. it will take time to understand what is going on but try it and enjoy.

```
<style>
div_base {
    width: 200px; // whatever size you want as constrain unchangeable
    max-width: 95%; // this is connected to img and mus exist
}
div_base img {
    width: auto !important;  // very important part just have it there!
    height: 95%;  // and this one is linked to maxW above. 
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using both width and max-width on the image screw up IE8.

Put the width on your image and wrap it in a div that has the max-width. (Then curse MS.)

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this with the following requirements:

1. Page must not get reflown when images load. The image sizes are known on the server side and calculations can be made.
2. Images must scale proportionally
3. Images must not be wider than the containing element
4. Images must not be scaled up, only down when necessary
5. Must use an img element and not a background to make sure the images also print properly
6. No JavaScript!

The closest I came up with is this terrible contraption. It requires three elements and two inline styles, but as far as I know this is the best way to scale images proportionally. All the `height: auto;` suggestions here negate the point of specifying the image dimensions on the server side and cause the content to jump around while loading.

```
.image {
  position: relative;
}

.image img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

<!-- container element with max-width prevents upscaling -->
<div class="image" style="max-width: 640px;">
  <!-- div with padding equal to the image aspect ratio to make
       the element the correct height -->
  <div style="padding-top: 75%;"></div>
  <!-- img scaled to completely fill container -->
  <img src="//placebear.com/640/480" />
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lqg1fgry/6/ - The "Hello" is there so you can see if the content after the image jumps around.

Answer (score -4):

```
function resizeBackground() {
    var scale=0; 
    var stageWidth=$(window).width(); 
    var newWidth=$("#myPic").width();
    var stageHeight=$(window).height();
    var newHeight=$("#myPic").height();
    if( $(window).width() > $(window).height() )  {
        scale = stageHeight/newHeight;
        scale = stageWidth/newWidth;
    } else {
        scale = stageWidth/newWidth;
        scale = stageHeight/newHeight;
    }
    newWidth = newWidth*scale;
    newHeight = newHeight*scale
    $("#myPic").width(newWidth);
    $("#myPic").height(newHeight);
}
```

Comment: You may want to explain how your code helps with the original question. Also, after formatting the code for readability, I can see that it recalculates `scale` twice for each `if/else` branch.

Comment: There is no an initial proportion of the picture in your code. You scale the image accordance to the page proportion.