# Scaling pictures

Tags: php, mysql, image

I'm displaying pictures within a div that is 350px x 350px big. People can upload pictures to my fileserver and a destination link to that picture is created in a database as well as an id. The php document getting the link is in the root folder and all pictures are saved in a subfolder called pictures. I show the picture using something like this:

```
$piclink = "SELECT `link` FROM `pictures` WHERE `id=`.$id.`";
```

The `$id` variable is stored when clicking a link from the previous page.

**My problem:** Not all pictures are the same format. I want to display them so that the *max* dimension is 350px, the other dimension according to proportion. How do I do this? Simply doing this:

```
echo "<img href=" . $piclink . " height='350px' width='350px'/>"
```

will stretch the picture to 350x350 thus breaking proportions. Any help appreciated.

Comment: There was a question with a good answer to this...

Comment: popnoodles, are you referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076284/scaling-images-proportionally-in-css-with-max-width ?

Comment: No, it can be done with CSS

Comment: check out the [Zebra Image](http://stefangabos.ro/php-libraries/zebra-image/) library

Comment: You don't have to specify both height and width. If you specify only one, the browser will scale the image and figure out the other dimension. You still need to figure out which side is longest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retain the aspect ratio, you can retrieve the image dimensions and apply the ratio using the 350px maximums.

Here's an example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="img-holder"></div>
```

**Code**

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
    alert('Orignal width:'+img.width+', height:'+img.height);
    var width, height;
    if (img.width > img.height) {
        width = (img.width > 350 ? 350 : img.width);
        height = img.height * (350 / img.width);
    } else {
        height = (img.height > 350 ? 350 : img.height);
        width = img.width * (350 / img.height);
    }
    img.width=width;
    img.height=height;
    $("#img-holder").append(img);
}
img.src = "http://mps.thebeautyquotient.com/images/val4a.jpeg"
```

Here's the jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/aN6Ec/